# передача в ostream объекта

Tags: c++

Есть такой код.

```
#include <iostream>
class Inko {
  public:
    Inko () {}
    void operator<<(const int &m)
    {
      i = m;
    }
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &m, const Inko &t)
    {
      m << t.i;
    }
  private:
    int i;
};

int main ( )
{
  Inko inko;
  inko << 12;
  std::cout << inko << std::end;
}
```

Можно как нибудь использовать operator<< без friend? С friend понятно всё, а вот как без friend можно использовать я не пойму.

Comment: Просто функция вне тела класса, которая принимает поток и экземпляр объекта класса.

Comment: @MrBin а что в функцию можно передать <<, а как такую функцию написать?

Comment: Точно также. Только без спецификатора `friend`.

Comment: @MrBin понел, спасибо.

Comment: @MrBin нет не понел. Функцию же надо как то назвать. Куда тогда девать operator<<?

Comment: ну вот_ называется  operator<<

Comment: @MrBin а всё, сделал.

Comment: inko << 12 это вы откуда придумали?

Comment: Пока поле `i` является `private` и других путей доступа нет, без `friend` не получится никак. Только `friend`. Поэтому о каком "сделал" вы ведете речь - не ясно.

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan, у него есть оператор.

Comment: @AnT ну я сделал в коде, который здесь не показал. Это я сделал уже после подсказки.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan я хотел попробывать можно ли так сделать.

Comment: @AnT а я понел что вам не ясно. Я сделал без объекта. Просто передав в функцию число, вот что получилось.

Comment: @xverizex, можно, но не нужно. Лучше для друга возвратите обьект ввода и инициализируйте  член в конструторе, не оставляйте его в неопределенном состоянии

Comment: А чем вам friend мешает? Он лишь говорит, что функция может работать с приватными полями класса `Inko`. Если вам это не нужно, можете friend убрать. Но в вашем примере это нужно, функция работает с приватными полем `i`

Comment: @ARHovsepyan я узнал что можно без friend делать функцию, которая не зависит от класса. И тоже её попробывал и всего то.